# Where is my Cloud Source Repositories on Google

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-tools

I am following the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/vcs. I push my code apparently successfully. But when I try to go see my code in the browser I cannot find

> In the left navigation bar, select Source Code > Browse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Tools->Development->Source Code

Answer (score 0):

As for as my knowledge goes, you could not see your uploaded source code in GAE console. I really appreciate that too, since as a owner you shall have the source code in your own development.

The reason might be more than that. However, GAE is providing option for downloading the source code from the GAE console.

Goto https://console.cloud.google.com/ Open Menu -> Tools -> Development

Use "Clone your Cloud Repository to a local Git repository" tab for downloading the code.

As a point of note, you could also disable the option of downloading the source code from the GAE. This is a better safer option, if you have good protection of your source code in your machine or somewhere.